# Why am I not get getting correct column positions in that parse tree?

Tags: c#, parsing, antlr4

Say I have a string like this:

```
var code = "Private Sub DoSomething(ByVal foo As Integer)\r\n    DoSomethingElse(foo)\r\nEnd Sub";
```

When I feed my ANTLR-generated parser with that string, I get a parse tree that looks something like this:

```
[SubStmtContext]
    [VisibilityContext]
    [ArgListContext]
        [ArgContext]
            [AmbiguousIdentifierContext]
            [AsTypeClauseContext]
    [BlockContext]
        [ImplicitCallStmt_InBlockContext]
            [ICS_B_SubCallContext]
                [CertainIdentifierContext]
                [ArgsCallContext]
                    [ArgCallContext]
                        [ValueStmtContext]
                            [ImplicitCallStmt_InStmtContext]
                                [ICS_S_VariableCallContext]
                                    [VariableCallStmtContext]
                                        [AmbiguousIdentifierContext]
```

The base `ParserRuleContext` class exposes `IToken Start` and `IToken Stop` properties, each of which expose a `Line` number, with a `StartIndex` and a `StopIndex`.

So back to my input string, I have the `DoSomething` identifier at line 1, column position start 12 and stop 22 - why is it that I have the `DoSomethingElse` identifier at line 2, column position start 51 and stop 65?

Is there a bug in ANTLR that makes it account for `\r\n` to determine line positions, but ignores them for column positions? I'm getting completely unreal column positions for anything other than the first line of parsed code... is there a way to have the above locate the `DoSomethingElse` identifier at line 2, column position start 4 and stop 18 where I'd expect them?

Here's the actual code that proceeds with the parsing:

```
    public IParseTree Parse(string code)
    {
        var input = new AntlrInputStream(code);
        var lexer = new VBLexer(input); // generated type
        var tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
        var parser = new VBParser(tokens); // generated type

        var result = parser.StartRule(); // generated method
        return result;
    }
```

The column positioning seems completely out of my control. Anyone else experienced this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Token` interface does not include a "column stop" property. However, it does include a method `getStopIndex()` which it sounds like you may be using. The `getStartIndex()` and `getStopIndex()` methods return the absolute indexes into the stream (from the beginning of parsing). To get the column within a line, use `getCharPositionInLine()` instead.